# Assembly: Convert Hex to Decimal

Tags: assembly, hex, decimal, nasm, dosbox

I am trying to get user input for a hex digit (0-9 or A-F) and output the result as decimal, as well as display an error message if the user puts in something outside the hex range, and repeats the whole process upon user's choice.

When trying to compile through NASM the program warns that the file cannot be opened. Is there something wrong with my code that is causing this error?

Ultimately I am trying to have this run in DOS BOX and compile successfully in NASM

*Edit: the code has been updated since, but is resulting in an infinte loop if a non hex value is entered and the continue, check for quit, and exit functions are not working properly/ not displaying as a result to users input 
Here is the code:

```
;this program takes input of hex and converts it to decimal format and repeats based on user input
org 100h
section .data

prompt0: db "Hello, my name is ####.    Let's do this....." 
prompt1: db "Please enter a hexadecimal digit: $"
prompt2: db 0Dh,0Ah, "In decimal it is:    $"
prompt3: db 0Dh,0Ah, "Do you want to do it again?: $"
prompt4: db 0Dh,0Ah, "Illegal character. -- Enter 0..9 or A..F: $"
buffer:  db "xxxxx"
endBuf:  db      ".$"
ten:     db      10

section .text   

start:  
mov     ah,9        ; print hello message
mov     dx,prompt0
int     21h

mov     ah,9        ; print prompt asking for hex
mov     dx,prompt1
int     21h
;input hex value 
mov     bx,0        ; bx holds input value
mov     ah,1        ; input char function
int     21h     ; read char into al


check1:
cmp     al, '0'     ; check if digit is 0-9
jl       top1       ; no? jump to chek if char
cmp     al, '9'     ; check if digit is withing 0-9
jg       top1       ; no? jump to check if char
sub     al, '0'     ; convert to decimal value
jmp     print_decimal       ; jump to print out in decimal

top1:   
cmp     al, 'A'     ; is char upercase?
jl      check_lower ; no? jump to check for lowercase
cmp     al, 'F'     ; is char within A-F?
jg      check_lower ; no? jump to check for lowercase
sub al, 'A'-10       ; convert to decimal
jmp     print_decimal       ; jump to print in decimal

check_lower:
cmp     al,'a'      ; is char lower case a-f?
jl      error       ; no? jump to error
cmp     al,'f'      ; is char lowercase a-f?
jg       error      ; no? jump to error
sub     al,'a'-10   ; convert to decimal

print_decimal:          ; print al as decimal 0-255
mov        di,endBuf    ; set buffer pointer to char after digit

next_digit:
dec     di      ; advance buffer pointer to next char
xor     ah, ah      ; clear highest byte ax for division
div     byte [ten]  ; ah = ax % 10
add    ah,'0'       ; convert ah to code
mov    [di], ah     ; copy to buffer
or     al, al       ; set condition codes to al
jnz    next_digit   ; jump if more digits available

print:  
mov     dx,prompt2  ; assign address for prompt2
mov     ah,9        ; print char fcn
int     21h     ; print it
mov     dx,di       ; offset address for converted decimal
mov     ah,9        ; print char fcn
int     21h     ; print it all
jmp     continue    ; repeat process

error:
mov     dx,prompt4  ; assign address to prompt4 
int      21h        ; print it all
jmp     continue    ; repeat process
continue:
mov      dx,prompt3
cmp      al,'Y'
je       start
cmp      al,'y'
je       start

;check for quit
cmp     al, 'N'     ; handle no/ quit character
je      Exit
cmp     al, 'n'
je      Exit

; return to DOS
Exit: 
    mov     ah, 04Ch      ; DOS function: Exit program 
    mov     al, 0         ; Return exit code value 
    int     21h           ; Call DOS. Terminate program
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assembly: How to convert hex input to decimal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21870702/assembly-how-to-convert-hex-input-to-decimal)

Comment: What program cannot open which file? NASM doesn't assemble the program (don't use the term "compile") due to undefined symbols (`decimal`, `endBuf` and `ten`). Show the command line to produce the `.com` file.

Comment: Dangerous to use `or al, al; jnz next_digit` because if the number was decimal `10` you'll print the `1` but skip the `0`.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, I noticed that the decimal, endBuf, and ten all came from the code I based part of mine off of from (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21870702/assembly-how-to-convert-hex-input-to-decimal ) and have made adjustments to that. @WeatherVane what line of code would you say I use as a way around that?