# reading from a text file and summing the hex values from the file

Tags: assembly, file-io, hex, x86-64

I am currently able to read from the file and print out the text from the file but I'm unable to convert the text to normal numbers to be able to sum them.

I need to be able to read every line and sum each line hex values.
the lines are :

```
0x3, 0x372, 0xab
0x3ed, 0x4444f
0x1, 0x12, 0x123, 0x1234, 0x123456, 0x1234567, 0x12345678, 0x123456789
```

I.E - first line should be printed as : 0x420

this is my current assembly code:

```
section .data
; -----
; Define standard constants.
LF equ 10 ; line feed
NULL equ 0 ; end of string
TRUE equ 1
FALSE equ 0
EXIT_SUCCESS equ 0 ; success code
STDIN equ 0 ; standard input
STDOUT equ 1 ; standard output
STDERR equ 2 ; standard error
SYS_read equ 0 ; read
SYS_write equ 1 ; write
SYS_open equ 2 ; file open
SYS_close equ 3 ; file close
SYS_fork equ 57 ; fork
SYS_exit equ 60 ; terminate
SYS_creat equ 85 ; file open/create
SYS_time equ 201 ; get time
O_CREAT equ 0x40
O_TRUNC equ 0x200
O_APPEND equ 0x400
O_RDONLY equ 000000q ; read only
O_WRONLY equ 000001q ; write only
O_RDWR equ 000002q ; read and write
S_IRUSR equ 00400q
S_IWUSR equ 00200q
S_IXUSR equ 00100q
; -----
; Variables/constants for main.
BUFF_SIZE equ 255 


newLine db LF, NULL
header db LF, ""
db LF, LF, NULL
fileName db "text.txt", NULL
fileDesc dq 0
errMsgOpen db "Error opening the file.", LF, NULL
errMsgRead db "Error reading from the file.", LF, NULL
; -------------------------------------------------------
section .bss
readBuffer resb BUFF_SIZE
; -------------------------------------------------------
section .text
global _start
_start:
mov r10,0
mov r9,0

global openInputFile
openInputFile:
mov rax, SYS_open 
mov rdi, fileName 
mov rsi, O_RDONLY 
syscall 
cmp rax, 0 
jl errorOnOpen
mov qword [fileDesc], rax 
mov rax, SYS_read


mov rdi, qword [fileDesc]
mov rsi, readBuffer
mov rdx, BUFF_SIZE
syscall
cmp rax, 0
jl errorOnRead

mov rsi, readBuffer
mov byte [rsi+rax], NULL
mov rdi, readBuffer
call printString

mov rax, SYS_close
mov rdi, qword [fileDesc]
syscall
jmp exampleDone

errorOnOpen:
mov rdi, errMsgOpen

jmp exampleDone


errorOnRead:
mov rdi, errMsgRead

jmp exampleDone

exampleDone:
mov rax, SYS_exit
mov rdi, EXIT_SUCCESS
syscall

global printString
printString:
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
push rbx

mov rbx, rdi
mov rdx, 0

strCountLoop:
cmp byte[rbx], NULL
je strCountDone
cmp byte[rbx],0x0a
inc r10
inc rdx
inc rbx
jmp strCountLoop

wordCalc:
cmp r10,1
je strCountLoop
add r9,rdx
cmp byte[rdx],0x0a
jmp strCountLoop



global strCountDone
strCountDone:
cmp rdx, 0
je prtDone


mov rax, SYS_write 
mov rsi, rdi 
mov rdi, STDOUT 

syscall 

global prtDone
prtDone:
mov r10,rbp
pop rbx
pop rbp
ret
```

I have tried to add the values from rbx to r9 so that I can print out the value of r9 for every row.
I have not yet implemented r9 print and r9 reset as I am unable to use the text as numbers yet and I don't know how to print r9 correctly.

Comment: Read each line, split on comma, convert each element into a number, sum them. Write it in C first if you're not clear on how to do it directly in assembly.

Comment: @Michael the problem is I seem to not succeed to conver them to numbers - I tried to sub 0x30 from each of them but it dosn’t work, I get odd results

Comment: A single subtraction of 0x30 only works if you have a single digit in the range `'0'..'9'`. What you've got is one _or more_ digits in the range `'0'..'F'` (plus a `"0x"` prefix). So you need a loop and some extra logic. Again, write it in C first if it helps.

Comment: @Michael will try and update with results.

Comment: [Assembly: How to convert hex input to decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21870702) has inefficient hex->integer for a single digit (16-bit code but easy to adapt).  https://github.com/zbjornson/fast-hex has some not-bad unhex (hex->binary integer) code, including a simple C scalar loop: https://github.com/zbjornson/fast-hex/blob/e104d6500f3e1c05f03151d1464396e13d12122b/src/hex.cc#L187